# Google script array problem (google sheet)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a problem understanding where I'm going wrong in my says on google script:

```
function new_date(){
  
  var tableau = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL_OK");
  var date_tabella = tableau.getRange("A2:A31");
  
  for(var i = 0; i<date_tabella.getValues().length; i++){

    Logger.log(date_tabella.getDisplayValues()[i]);
    Logger.log(new Date(date_tabella.getValues()[i]));

  }
}
```

I get this output, and I don't understand why:

I'll put a translation IT -> ENG

```
Notifica -> Notification
Informazioni -> Information
Esecuzione avviata -> Execution started
Esecuzione completata -> Execution completed
lun,mar,mer,gio,ven,sab,dom -> mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun (week days)
```

```
19:45:36    Notifica    Esecuzione avviata
19:45:36    Informazioni    [lun 01/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Sun Mar 31 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [mar 02/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Mon Apr 01 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [mer 03/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Tue Apr 02 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [gio 04/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Wed Apr 03 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [ven 05/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Thu Apr 04 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [sab 06/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Fri Apr 05 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [dom 07/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Sat Apr 06 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [lun 08/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Sun Apr 07 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [mar 09/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Mon Apr 08 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [mer 10/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Tue Apr 09 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [gio 11/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Wed Apr 10 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [ven 12/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Thu Apr 11 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [sab 13/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Fri Apr 12 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [dom 14/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Sat Apr 13 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [lun 15/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Sun Apr 14 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [mar 16/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Mon Apr 15 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [mer 17/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Tue Apr 16 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [gio 18/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Wed Apr 17 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [ven 19/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Thu Apr 18 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [sab 20/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Fri Apr 19 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [dom 21/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Sat Apr 20 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [lun 22/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Sun Apr 21 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [mar 23/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Mon Apr 22 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [mer 24/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Tue Apr 23 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [gio 25/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Wed Apr 24 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [ven 26/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Thu Apr 25 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:36    Informazioni    [sab 27/04/2024]
19:45:36    Informazioni    Fri Apr 26 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:37    Informazioni    [dom 28/04/2024]
19:45:37    Informazioni    Sat Apr 27 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:37    Informazioni    [lun 29/04/2024]
19:45:37    Informazioni    Sun Apr 28 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:37    Informazioni    [mar 30/04/2024]
19:45:37    Informazioni    Mon Apr 29 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2024
19:45:38    Notifica    Esecuzione completata
```

The table from which I get the array is this:

[Table used in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2sPH.png)

I would like clarification on these points:

- Why is the first element set to the default date? (by moving the indices the last element also behaves in the same way)
- Why are the outputs all offset by 1?

I would expect that for each index of the array to have as first output value the value written in the table, as second output the value converted to DATE

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand the first question.  As to the second one, if I understood it correctly, the parsed dates are offset because they include time zone information `GMT-04:00`.  What to do about that depends on what you need these dates for.

Comment: I think you solved my problem.
Is it possible that it is something related to the time zone of the table?

The table is set to a GTM +1 time zone. Why should -4 come out?

I'll do some tests. Thank you very much.

Comment: Script might have its own time zone, although it is usually the same as the spreadsheet's.  You can check it in `appsscript.json`.  To enable it, you need to got to script Project Settings and enable "Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor".  After that go back to the script and check `appsscript.json`.

Comment: @dataful.tech Consider adding it as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    10:38:57    Notifica    Esecuzione avviata
10:38:57    Informazioni    lun 01/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    mar 02/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Tue Apr 02 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    mer 03/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Wed Apr 03 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    gio 04/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    ven 05/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Fri Apr 05 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    sab 06/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Sat Apr 06 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    dom 07/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Sun Apr 07 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    lun 08/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Mon Apr 08 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    mar 09/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Tue Apr 09 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    mer 10/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Wed Apr 10 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    gio 11/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Thu Apr 11 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    ven 12/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Fri Apr 12 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    sab 13/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Sat Apr 13 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    dom 14/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Sun Apr 14 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    lun 15/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Mon Apr 15 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    mar 16/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Tue Apr 16 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    mer 17/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Wed Apr 17 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    gio 18/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Thu Apr 18 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    ven 19/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Fri Apr 19 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    sab 20/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Sat Apr 20 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    dom 21/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Sun Apr 21 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    lun 22/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Mon Apr 22 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    mar 23/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Tue Apr 23 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    mer 24/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Wed Apr 24 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    gio 25/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Thu Apr 25 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    ven 26/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Fri Apr 26 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    sab 27/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Sat Apr 27 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    dom 28/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Sun Apr 28 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    lun 29/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Mon Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    mar 30/04/2024
10:38:57    Informazioni    Tue Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2024
10:38:59    Notifica    Esecuzione completata
```

The cause of the problem is the one reported in the comments of this question.

The error was caused by the fact that the time zone relating to Google Script was incorrect.

Apparently the time zone is not "synchronized" with that of the Google Sheet automatically.

Thank you all. Problem solved.

special thanks to @dataful.tech who identified the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function new_date(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rg = ss.getRange("A2:A10");
  var vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}
```

DATA:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 |
| 2 | 1/1/2024 |
| 3 | 1/2/2024 |
| 4 | 1/3/2024 |
| 5 | 1/4/2024 |
| 6 | 1/5/2024 |
| 7 | 1/6/2024 |
| 8 | 1/7/2024 |
| 9 | 1/8/2024 |
| 10 | 1/9/2024 |

```
Execution log
12:40:53 PM Notice  Execution started
12:40:48 PM Info    [["1/1/2024"],["1/2/2024"],["1/3/2024"],["1/4/2024"],["1/5/2024"],["1/6/2024"],["1/7/2024"],["1/8/2024"],["1/9/2024"]]
12:40:56 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

It returns a 2 dimensional array even for just one column.  So in your case if you wish to refer to each cell value it would be `vs[i][0]`